# Possible to retrieve MediaWiki data for a section by using section title instead of rvsection id?

Tags: json, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to retrieve section data. The only way I found this is possible is by using the **rvsection** parameter. Is there a way to get section data by the section title?

**rvsection** is used like this: http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Abyssal_demon&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&rvsection=3

changing the rvsection number determines the data you get.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple sections with the same title?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think that is possible as all the items are already in the wikia. I should investigate this :). It only searches for the perfect name, so if I would type in  Abyssal_Demon with a capital D it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to directly get the section contents based on the section name.

What you can do is to get the section name to section index mapping first:

http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=parse&page=Abyssal_demon&prop=sections&format=jsonfm

And use that to figure out the section index of the section that you want.

One possible issue with this approach is what happens when the article changes between the two queries. To solve that, you can make the first query also return revision id:

http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=parse&page=Abyssal_demon&prop=sections|revid&format=jsonfm

And then use that in your second query:

http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&revids=251305&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&rvsection=3